# Just want to say how happy I am with the Aviation SE site

Tags: discussion

This is not a question.  So feel free to delete it.  That being said...

I created the proposal for this site back in high school (8 years ago) when I was working on my PPL.  I was very involved in promoting the proposal, and the beta.  It slowly gained popularity, and I wasn't sure it would ever be successful.  Users like Lnafziger and Peter Kämpf quickly "took over" the community and really rocketed into success.

Into college I really slipped out of the community, but would continue to use it every one-in-a-while.

After college I joined the Air Force and am currently in F-16 B-Course training.  Needless to say, most of the information I need nowadays is contained in F-16 community, and different than most GA-type questions.

However, every so often I'll be searching around on Google and come across a post from this site.  It makes me beyond happy to see what the site has become, and how many people it's helped.  It's awesome to see the scope of questions that people ask, and the amount of knowledge from users and moderators who answer them.

You guys are awesome!

Edit: [just found the proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation).  6.9 questions per day... nice.

Comment: And a big thank you for proposing it!

Comment: Thank you Keegan. It's nice to hear from you. You can share your knowledge by writing answers to common questions people want to know about F-16.

Comment: Wait ... are you the founder of the site?